# Как убрать скобки python

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть код, который берет из базы данных значения.

```
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id>0 ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 20")
        row = cur.fetchall()
        result = row[0]
        print (result)
```

Но при выводе он выдает значения со скобками.

```
(id, 0)
```

Как можно это убрать?

Comment: Это кортежи. Ну, берите из них нужную часть типа так `result[1]`

Comment: `print(*result)`

Answer (score 1):

Вы выводите полную строку, а Вам нужно выводить с разделение (0, 1):

```
print(result[0])
```